# acessar dados do banco de dados de uma colula específica

Tags: python, sqlite3

Tenho um banco de dados com uma tabela lista_alunos, campo str(nome) e campo str(serie), alguem consegue me explicar o por quê não consigo acessar os nomes que contenham somente as series que eu passei?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('bd/obj.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT nome FROM lista_alunos WHERE serie = ?', botao.text,)
for i in c.fetchall():
    print(i[3])
conn.close()
```

O botao.text também é uma string.

Comment: Sua consulta retorna só uma coluna e no laço `for` você tenta imprimir uma quarta coluna inexistente. Onde está `print(i[3])` faça `print(i[0])`.

Comment: Já havia testado, e s'consegui acessr o i[0] colocando buffer(botao.text). O qeu achei bem estranho pois qundo tento com outras colunas ele aceita sem o buffer.

Comment: No `execute` tem uma virgula sobrando após `botao.text`.

Comment: Na verdade a vírgula é necessário pois o segundo argumento é uma tupla, mas mesmo do jeito que está, quando eu acesso outra coluna que não seja série ele imprime os valores normalmente.

Comment: Consegui resolver, alterei a forma como gravo o dado no BD, tirei o sqlite3.binary() e funcionou.